# Custom Padding Widget on Flutter

Tags: flutter

*Hello Everyone;
I'm trying to make a custom widget that extends EdgeInsets class. I want a custom widget because i will use it in my project like that;
`CustomPadding.all(20) - CustomPadding.only(top: 10)`
How can i use like this? Thanks you all.*

*I am using like this for now;*

```
class ProjectDecorations {
static const EdgeInsets homepage3dotsPadding = EdgeInsets.only(right: 5);
static const EdgeInsets centerImgPadding = EdgeInsets.only(top: 180);
static const EdgeInsets loginButtonTopPadding = EdgeInsets.only(top: 100);
static const EdgeInsets createAccountTopPadding = EdgeInsets.only(top: 20);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a file that you can name constants.dart, inside this file set your custom padding and you can name it depending on the context you'll use each one of them as follows:

```
const EdgeInsets kRegularPadding = EdgeInsets.all(20);
const EdgeInsets kTopPadding = EdgeInsets.only(top: 10);
```

Now you can use it in your code as follows:

```
class SampleCode extends StatelessWidget {
  const SampleCode({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: kRegularPadding,
      margin: kTopPadding,
      child: YourWidget()
    );
  }
}
```

Don't forget to import the file constants.dart